# Unnecessary local variable - is good practice to write redundant variable to be more clear?

Tags: php, variables, inline

Is good practice to write redundant variable to be more clear?

```
$arrImages = array_slice($arrImages, $offset, self::LIMIT_IMAGES);
return $arrImages;
```

Comment: It's entirely up to you, and what coding standards you want to apply to your code. There's no right or wrong answer which everyone would agree on, so we can't answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no much difference between the 2 ways anyway

it all depends on your personal preferences, and also the project conventions.